# python 3.x tqdm: percentage completed over total percentage progress bar

Tags: python-3.x, file, progress-bar

I want to use `tqdm` to show the progress bar of the file transfer. However, I can't apply the normal way of using `tqdm`, as in

```
t =tqdm(total=100)
for i in range(10):
    t.update(10)
t.close()
```

The reason is that I have a function that receives a progress callback so that every time the callback is called inside the function, it would receive two parameters, `consumed_bytes` and `total_bytes`. This resembles the following code:

```
def progress_bar(consumed_bytes, total_bytes):
    print(consumed_bytes, total_bytes)

file_transfer(..., progress_callback=progressbar)
```

Therefore, if I were to use the following way to present the progress bar (a modified version of  the first code block posted above):

```
def progress_bar (consumed_bytes, total_bytes):
    t = tqdm(total=total_bytes)
    t.update(consumed_byets)
    t.close()

file_transfer(..., progress_callback=progressbar)
```

The console would print multiple progress bars, as shown below,

```
  8%|▊         | 8192/107647 [00:00<00:00, 45509587.24B/s]
 15%|█▌        | 16384/107647 [00:00<00:00, 105722271.90B/s]
 23%|██▎       | 24576/107647 [00:00<00:00, 169259794.92B/s]
 30%|███       | 32768/107647 [00:00<00:00, 194122815.64B/s]
 38%|███▊      | 40960/107647 [00:00<00:00, 213149741.74B/s]
 46%|████▌     | 49152/107647 [00:00<00:00, 372127130.34B/s]
 53%|█████▎    | 57344/107647 [00:00<00:00, 445404015.88B/s]
 61%|██████    | 65536/107647 [00:00<00:00, 336036561.06B/s]
 68%|██████▊   | 73728/107647 [00:00<00:00, 555184282.43B/s]
 76%|███████▌  | 81920/107647 [00:00<00:00, 500141752.08B/s]
 84%|████████▎ | 90112/107647 [00:00<00:00, 692229161.26B/s]
 91%|█████████▏| 98304/107647 [00:00<00:00, 744254260.68B/s]
 99%|█████████▉| 106496/107647 [00:00<00:00, 924796270.77B/s]
100%|██████████| 107647/107647 [00:00<00:00, 785224769.89B/s]
```

but I want it to display just one progress bar. Is it possible to display just one progress bar with the mechanism of the code described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t = tqdm(total=total_bytes)` is used to instantiate a `tqdm` object, and every time a `tqdm` object is instantiated, it will print out an extra progress bar.

So my suggestion is that move this line out of `progress_bar` function which should only be used for update a pre-instantiated`tqdm` object, close the `tqdm` object after the file transfer completed.